# running piped cmd in python - different results

Tags: python, command, call, subprocess, pipe

I am trying to invoke the piped command (echo -e "HEAD / HTTP/1.0\n" |  ncat -C localhost 80) in python.

```
from subprocess import call
cmd = 'echo -e "HEAD / HTTP/1.0\n" |  ncat -C localhost 80'
output=call(cmd, shell=True)
print output
```

However, the results are different than expected:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
...
```

Expected result (when running that cmd from shell) is:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Redirect
...
```

Update: 
I just experimented and this seems to work perfectly.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p1 = Popen(['echo', 'HEAD / HTTP/1.0\n'], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["ncat", "-C", "localhost", "80"], stdin=p1.stdout)
p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `\n` is generating a newline in the *python* string. I'm assuming you wanted `echo` to interpret that. Try making it a raw string:

```
cmd = r'echo -e "HEAD / HTTP/1.0\n" |  ncat -C localhost 80'
```

That way, python won't interpret the '\n' and it'll be passed along.

Comment: Yeah, after thinking on it even though it's a literal newline so a slightly different command, the newline is inside double quotes so it should still be a newline in the output.